# Installing Podman DNSname - install: cannot stat 'bin/dnsname': No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, containers, podman, dnsmasq

I am new to actually posing questions but here ya go.

I have been attempting to follow the install guide to add dnsname:

https://github.com/containers/dnsname
https://github.com/containers/dnsname/blob/main/README_PODMAN.md

I am having a problem though with this step:

```
make install PREFIX=/usr -- this will install the dnsname plugin into /usr/libexec/cni where your CNI plugins should already exist.
```

when I try to run it I get this error:

```
theuser@thecomputer:/usr/bin/dnsname$ make install PREFIX=/usr
install  -d -m 755 /usr/libexec/cni
install  -m 755 bin/dnsname /usr/libexec/cni/dnsname
install: cannot stat 'bin/dnsname': No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:76: install] Error 1
```

Ive tried running it in ~ as well but that doesnt change anything. I am lost as what to do as I have not installed Git Binaries very often (if at all). I haven't found anything by searching to understand what step I am missing or piece I don't have installed.

I am running:
Ubuntu 21.10

I have made sure to install:
make and its dependencies
go
podman
dnsmasq

Comment: I can't say for sure without looking closer or trying it, but I suspect they left out the `make PREFIX=/usr` step that you probably need before `make PREFIX=/usr install`.

Comment: make PREFIX=/usr install produces the same results.

I figure I am missing some basic component about setting up binary installs. I haven't been able to find something online that matches.

Comment: In a typical project setup, `make` (with any options needed) would build the software. Some makefiles are smart enough to build first if you run `make install` without having run `make` first, and presumably their instructions assume this. If `make` alone isn't working, something more serious is wrong, but what that would be, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

OK!
so torek helped me here.
I needed to run just:

make PREFIX=/usr

in the directory BEFORE

make install PREFIX=/usr

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, so basically: missing from https://github.com/containers/dnsname/blob/main/README_PODMAN.md:

```
sudo yum -y install dnsmasq
git clone https://github.com/containers/dnsname.git
cd dnsname
make PREFIX=/usr
sudo make install PREFIX=/usr
```